# Update firestore only once with the offline cached state after user becomes online

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

While being in offline mode user performs 1000+ write actions to the unique collection bound to that particular user, where only he/she has access to. After a while it reconnects to the network...

Is there a way rather then passing all queued actions, update the firestore with current version of the state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no support for folding the pending writes, as each state change might individually be accepted/rejected by the server-side security rules, and might individually trigger server-side behavior (like Cloud functions).